# Get template associated with a controller inside that controller itself

Tags: angularjs, templates

Is there any Injectable providers available for controllers to get partials template on which controller the same is applied.
Like

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
<div>

angular.module("app")
.controller("TestController",function([$templateProvider]){
});
```

I want to get

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    <div>
```

element inside my TestController

Is there any template built-in providers available in angularjs??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `$rootElement`.
But its giving complete ng-app element.
We can use querySelector to get the partials from `$rootElement`.

> The root element of Angular application. This is either the element
>   where ngApp was declared or the element passed into angular.bootstrap.
>   The element represents the root element of application. It is also the
>   location where the application's $injector service gets published, and
>   can be retrieved using $rootElement.injector().